# Why is it better to use '!=" than '<' in a vector loop? (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, loops

Why is it better to use '!=" than '<' in a vector loop? I just can't see the difference.

Comment: If you intend to use openmp, `<` is actually better than `!=` (the last one is not a valid controlling predicate).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because you're using iterators, and it'll make the loop look exactly the same as other containers, should you choose to switch to other container types, such as set, list, unordered_set, etc. where < has no meaning.

Answer (score 8):

I'll assume that you mean the use of `!=vector.end()` rather than `<vector.size()` as that was not clear from your question.

One reason to prefer the end() version is that what you are really trying to do is to check whether you reached the end.

The idiom for doing this sort of checks for arrays in C was to check the index compared to the size, but that is a "legacy" behavior. In was then spread in the world of Java (as <`array.length`) until such time that people realized that arrays are evil and that Java finally supports generics. In C++, however, there is no reason to use this idiom when you have a good collection class such as vector to work with. It's more readable, and more maintainable. For example, it makes it easier to switch to other collections if necessary, as you are still talking about the end.

Answer (score 6):

Some iterator types don't support the less-than operator -- they only support the inequality operator.  That's why you'll often see the less-than operator forsaken.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I like to put code like this in a template function similar to the STL algorigthms, such that they are agnostic about what the underlying containter is.

Since < only makes sense for vectors, it would be a poor fit for a generic function.  If you use <, you are locking yourself into using a vector.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the programmer remembered a defensive coding trick: In case something goes haywire during the loop's execution, and the index/pointer/iterator goes way past the end, the loop will quietly stop upon checking '<' leaving the bug unnoticed. With != there's likely to be chaos and a crash as the loop continues with bad data, allowing an earlier fix.

Comment: Except some iterators don't allow for < so in that case the code would not compile or work. The reason it is used is so that you can switch out the container without having to modify the for loop.

Comment: +1: This defensive coding trick also allows you to statically analyze and prove the correctness of your loop. If the loop terminates normally, then the `a!=b` condition tells you that it terminated because exactly `a==b`, e.g. the loop body was executed the exact number of times you expected. The `a<b` condition only tells you that it terminated because `a>=b`, e.g. the loop body was executed at least the number of times you expected, maybe more. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132164/loop-termination-conditions

Comment: This defensive coding trick also makes the program robust against [Cloudbleed](https://blog.cloudflare.com/incident-report-on-memory-leak-caused-by-cloudflare-parser-bug/)-type scenarios. And the computer doesn't do extra work. The downside is the aforementioned loss of generality.

Answer (score 1):

For vector iterators, it doesn't make any difference. In general, iterators may not support '<' just '==' and '!='. Hence, the most general way to test if you have not reached the end of the collection is to check if the iterator != container.end()

Answer (score -1):

Another reason: When translated into assembly, a branch-equal or branch-not-equal is generally *much* faster than a comparison branch.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for that?  I'd always assumed in either case it's basically a subtraction - in the eq/neq case you check the zero flag and in the less than case you check the negative flag.