# In C++ why can't we compare iterators using > and <?

Tags: c++, loops, syntax, iterator, idioms

I have been asked this question which I do not really know why.

If you have a pointer `int * x;`
You can compare pointers with `>` and `<` because it stands for the memory location something like `0x0000 0x0004 0x0008`, etc. I know iterators and pointers are different, but they act in a very similar way.

For example:

```
vector<int> myVector;

for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
{
    myVector.push_back(i);
}

vector<int>::iterator it = myVector.begin();
while(it != myVector.end()) //Why can't we write it < myVector.end()
{
    cout << *it << endl;
    it++;
}
```

Why can't we write it `< myVector.end()` in the `while` statement?
I know it has to do with no overloading in STL. However, writing `&*it < &*myVector.end()` works because it gets the memory location which reveals say `0x0004 0x0008`, etc.

Why is this?

Comment: [What do you mean?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b5dfc7353b93dc6)

Comment: Also related: [Why is it better to use '!=" than '<' in a vector loop? (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871666/why-is-it-better-to-use-than-in-a-vector-loop-c)

Comment: Mind you, you can only use `<` on two pointers _to the same array_, but not on unrelated pointers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`operator<` and `operator>` can only be used with [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). But `operator!=` could also be used with [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) and [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). For your sample code, `it != myVector.end()` and `it < myVector.end()` have the same effect, but the former is more general, then the code also works with other iterators (e.g. iterators of `std::list` or `std::map` etc).

BTW: Your sample code will be fine to use `operator<` or `operator>`, since the iterator of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types) is `RandomAccessIterator`.

Comment: Should be noted, though, that to be comparable, both iterators need to be in the same domain (iterating over same vector or whatever underlying class).

Comment: I actually tried it with g++ along with -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11. It does not compile when you write it < myVector.end()

Comment: @user4099855 What's the error message? Did you check the comment of LogicStuff?

Comment: Why the downvote? Where am I wrong?

Comment: @songyuanyao Again one of those un-understandable ones - there seem to be some people randomly picking answers for downvoting...

Comment: @user4099855 I tried with GCC and `-std=c++11` [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e87815aadedfdcfa). It should be fine.

Comment: @user4099855 worked for me, too, even with gcc 4.8.4 (`-std=c++1y`).

Comment: Didn't the concept of `std::vector::iterator` actually change to ContiguousIterator? There's no page on cppreference yet so I can't easily check

Comment: @KABoissonneault The [accurate description](http://eel.is/c++draft/containers#container.requirements.general-13) is "A contiguous container is a container that supports random access iterators ([random.access.iterators]) and whose member types iterator and const_iterator are contiguous iterators ([iterator.requirements.general])."

Comment: So, using `<` or `>` instead of `!=` **constraints** your generic algorithm to *random-access* iterators.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector::iterator` is a random access iterator, and you can certainly compare them with `<` and `>`.

However, only random access iterators can be compared using anything other than `==` and `!=`. Bidirectional, forward, and input iterators only define the equality/inequality comparison operators.

A `std::list::iterator`, for example is an iterator pointing to some unspecified member of a `std::list`. In this case, there's just no meaning to any other kind of a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<` and `>` **cannot** be always used with iterators, because only some kinds of iterators support such operations (namely, random access iterators and the like). On the other hand, comparison operations such as `!=` is *always* available.

Now, why care about using `<` and `>` if `!=` has the same effect and always works?

---

Suppose you have some generic code:

```
template <class It>
void foo(It begin, It end)
{
    while (--end != begin)
        apply(*begin);

}
```

The code will compile for pointers, for example, but it won't for `myList.begin()`.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting?

Comment: Question was *'Why ...?'*, you're just giving an example, not the reason for (though downvote wasn't mine...).

Comment: @Aconcagua Well, I think the reason is clear enough (_"only a few kinds of iterators support those operations"_) and the example shows a possible scenario for the issue.

Comment: I admit, the cited sentence actually *is* the answer to the question. It is somehow shadowed by your code example, though, a little bit as if you had a large flyer 'Hey see the drawback' and the explanation only in the fine print. You would have avoided the effect if the explanation was the first sencence of your answer...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for the tip! (I wasn't trying to accuse you, naturally)