# Check Iterator Poinitng to first element of a string

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I have a function and I am passing an iterator and a string to check whether the iterator is pointing to the first element or not. 
However, I am getting unexpected results.

```
int main()
{
 std::string str="abc";
 std::string::iterator strit = str.begin();
 iteratorProperty(strit, str);
}

void iteratorProperty(std::string::iterator it, std::string str) {
//std::next(it);
int count = 0;
for(auto i = it; i <str.end();i++) {

    count++;
}
std::cout<<count<<std::endl;
}
```

This cout statement is returning me a value of 51.
Could anyone please help me understand this?

Thank You.

Comment: `str` is a copy. your begin and end iterators are incompatible, they belong to different strings.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. I am so Stupid. This was a dumb question.

Comment: @goodfellas95 No, the question is a valid one.  Maybe just remove the confusing main() line, since you neither open nor close the function body.  And tell the expected value ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was passing a shallow copy instead of a deep copy.

That's why I was getting undefined values.

Correct signature:

```
void iteratorProperty(std::string::iterator it, std::string& str) {
```

Comment: When you pass by reference there is no copying at all.  You are literally using the object from the call site in the function.

Comment: Another change that you should consider is to avoid `<` with iterators and prefer `!=` (see here why: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38121032/3723423)